# Is this set a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$? $U=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 4t^{3}\\t^{2}\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{2}:t\in\mathbb{R} \right\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> Is this set a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$?
>   $$U=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
> 4t^{3}\\t^{2}\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{2}:t\in\mathbb{R}
> \right\}$$

I think we can say the answer really fast because if we set $t=0$, we will have

$$\begin{pmatrix}
4\cdot0^{3} \\ 
0^{2}
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
0  
\end{pmatrix}$$

Thus the empty set is included which means that the set $U$ is not a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Is it correct or that's not enough to conclude this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what are you meaning by saying that empty set is included. $(0,0)$ has to be included if it is a linear subspace. In this case, it is included. But it is not linear just using the definition of what a linear subspace is. 
For example, if $(x,y)\in U \Rightarrow (-x,-y)\in U$, but the second coordinate of $U$ is always positive.

Answer (score 1):

When you are confused, operate by definition.

Check for scalar multiplication. For all $v \in U$, it should happen that $c \cdot v \in U$, for all $c \in \mathbb R$. Does this happen?

No, it does not. For example, put $t=1$, and you see that $(4,1) \in U$. However, taking $c=-1$, $(-1)(4,1) = (-4,-1) \notin U$, since for no real $t$ is it true that $t^2=-1$.

Hence, your $U$ cannot possibly be a subspace. However, it does contain the point $(0,0)$, which is a requirement, if that is what you meant.